# VBA - strip hidden HTML from cells in Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have an order form on an Excel worksheet. The values in some of the cells must be very specific values in order for other functions to work right.

I'm not sure how it happened, but at least two of the cells had what looked to be simply a trailing space after the value. It turns out that the problem was that the text had hidden `<p>` tags wrapped around them.

The Trim function doesn't fix it. What would get rid of the `<p>` tags and presumably any other hidden HTML in an Excel cell?

Comment: `Substitute` function? Also, `Left`, `Right`, `Mid`, `Search`, `Find`. All those may help directly or indirectly depending upon text string pattern. If it's very complex then a UDF in VBA may be necessary.

Comment: Would there be a way to strip out non alphanumeric characters?

Comment: All those functions I mentioned work with non-alphanumeric characters. There is no built-in excel function to strip out non-alphanumeric. You have to be creative with what excel does have or go with VBA for a UDF (which is another way of being creative with Excel's tools).